# How to format date and time in Android?

Tags: android, date, time, formatting, format

How to format correctly according to the device configuration date and time when having a year, month, day, hour and minute?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Use the standard Java DateFormat class.

For example to display the current date and time do the following:

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

You can initialise a Date object with your own values, however you should be aware that the constructors have been deprecated and you should really be using a Java Calendar object.

Comment: This is the android.text.format.DateFormat rather than java.text.DateFormat.

Comment: It's pretty typical of Android IME to have two classes that both claim to give you a result that is set to the default Locale but one doesn't. So yes, don't forget to use the android.text.format version of DateFormat (that doesn't even derive the java.util one LOL).

Comment: am having problem with what i should import - i mean lib files :(

Comment: Please note this line: `DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());` The returned dateFormat is of type `java.text.DateFormat` (and NOT `android.text.format.DateFormat`)

Comment: @Harsha - to get around that issue, I chain my use of DateFormat so I only have to reference the Android class and therefore there aren't any ambiguous classes.

final String dateStr = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).format(d);

You can use Android's format() method and have (IMHO) cleaner code and one less Object to instantiate.

Comment: This formatter only includes the date, not the time as the original question stated. Use DateUtils from the same package instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983920/display-date-and-time-in-user-locale

Comment: Unfortunately this may not work on all devices.  I'm testing with a HTC desire with "Select date format" in settings as ddd, MMM dd, yyyy and the dateformatter is returning MM/dd/yy!

Comment: For a full format, use an api. android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(Context);

Comment: @JerryBrady your way is cleaner, you may want to consider writing it up as a separate answer.

Answer (score 235):

In my opinion, `android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)` makes me confused because this method returns `java.text.DateFormat` rather than `android.text.format.DateFormat` - -".

So, I use the fragment code as below to get the current date/time in my format.

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
df.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());

or

android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
```

In addition, you can use others formats. Follow *[DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)*.

Comment: Useful, but the question said "according to the device configuration". To me that implies using a format chosen based on the user's language/country, or chosen directly by the user, rather than hardcoding the choice of format.

Comment: also, don't forget that `hh:mm:ss` will give you `01:00:00` for 1 PM, you'll need to use `kk:mm:ss` to get `13:00:00`

Comment: @dnet `k` is hour in day (1-24), do you not mean `H`, which is hour in day (0-23), eg. HH:mm:ss?
See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Joony no, there's difference between `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` (what you linked and uses `H` for hours in the 0-23 range) and `android.text.format.DateFormat` (what the answer is about and uses `k` for hours in the 0-23 range)

Comment: @dnet After testing, you are correct about `k`, however, the documentation for `DateFormat` clearly states _For the canonical documentation of format strings, see SimpleDateFormat._  Very confusing.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems like format is a static method in android.text.format.DateFormat.

Comment: @Joony I see your confusion and I had a huge WTF moment, see [this commit for `android...DateFormat`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/fc55c2ba49957bb696b98d290964dc36f4827190), but it seems `SimpleDateFormat` works as intended.

Comment: You can use also android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat().

Answer (score 225):

You can use `DateFormat`. Result depends on default Locale of the phone, but you can specify Locale too :

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

This is results on a

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date)
```

FR Locale : 3 nov. 2017

US/En Locale : Jan 12, 1952

---

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 03/11/2017

US/En Locale : 12.13.52

---

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 3 nov. 2017

US/En Locale : Jan 12, 1952

---

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 3 novembre 2017

US/En Locale : January 12, 1952

---

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(date)
```

FR Locale : vendredi 3 novembre 2017

US/En Locale : Tuesday, April 12, 1952

---

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date)
```

FR Locale :  3 nov. 2017 16:04:58

---

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 03/11/2017 16:04

---

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 03/11/2017 16:04:58

---

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.LONG).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 03/11/2017 16:04:58 GMT+01:00

---

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.FULL).format(date)
```

FR Locale :  03/11/2017 16:04:58 heure normale d’Europe centrale

---

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(date)
```

FR Locale : 16:04:58

---

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 16:04

---

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 16:04:58

---

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 16:04:58 GMT+01:00

---

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(date)
```

FR Locale : 16:04:58 heure normale d’Europe centrale

---

Comment: Thank you for putting all these cases in one place. If you could add cases for time only as well, this will make it a complete reference.

Comment: I am asking why the documentation is not so esaustive, Many thanks

Comment: For pattern approach use `DateFormat.getPatternInstance("dMMMMyyyyHHmm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date)` -> `December 23, 2005, 17:37`

Comment: it actually says AM and PM instead of 24 hour how to fix that?

Answer (score 43):

Date to Locale date string:

```
Date date = new Date();
String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
```

Options:

```
   DateFormat.getDateInstance()
```

- > Dec 31, 1969

```
   DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
```

-> Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM

```
   DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
```

-> 4:00:00 PM

Comment: How to remove year from DateFormat.getDateInstance()  ?

Answer (score 25):

### Date and Time format explanation

```
EEE : Day ( Mon )
MMMM : Full month name ( December ) // MMMM February   
MMM : Month in words ( Dec )
MM : Month ( 12 )
dd : Day in 2 chars ( 03 )
d: Day in 1 char (3)
HH : Hours ( 12 )
mm : Minutes ( 50 )
ss : Seconds ( 34 )
yyyy: Year ( 2020 ) //both yyyy and YYYY are same
YYYY: Year ( 2020 )
zzz : GMT+05:30
a : ( AM / PM )
aa : ( AM / PM )
aaa : ( AM / PM )
aaaa : ( AM / PM )
```

Comment: Capital YYYY may crush in some cases, better use lower case one

Comment: lowercase "hh" is 12 hour time, uppercase "HH" is 24 hour time

Comment: This might be useful but doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 21):

This will do it:

```
Date date = new Date();
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Will this get localized when user changes the language in an android device?

Answer (score 17):

**Use SimpleDateFormat**

Like this:

```
event.putExtra("starttime", "12/18/2012");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(bundle.getString("starttime"));
```

Comment: Yes, with **default locale** to avoid performance issues: `new SimpleDateFormat("my-format", Locale.getDefault());`

Answer (score 16):

**Here is the simplest way:**

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);

    String time = df.format(new Date());
```

and If you are looking for **patterns**, check this
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 14):

Following this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

Is better to use Android native Time class:

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

Then format:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "Time "+now.format("%d.%m.%Y %H.%M.%S"));
```

Comment: @FireZenk: According to the [link]( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) you provided: _This class has a number of issues and it is recommended that GregorianCalendar is used instead_.

Comment: Oh... this issue-info is newer than my comment, so that's a deprecated answer

Answer (score 10):

Use these two as a class variables:

```
 public java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 private Calendar mDate = null;
```

And use it like this:

```
 mDate = Calendar.getInstance();
 mDate.set(year,months,day);                   
 dateFormat.format(mDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 9):

This is my method, you can define and input and output format.

```
public static String formattedDateFromString(String inputFormat, String outputFormat, String inputDate){
    if(inputFormat.equals("")){ // if inputFormat = "", set a default input format.
        inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    }
    if(outputFormat.equals("")){
        outputFormat = "EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy"; // if inputFormat = "", set a default output format.
    }
    Date parsed = null;
    String outputDate = "";

    SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, java.util.Locale.getDefault());

    // You can set a different Locale, This example set a locale of Country Mexico.
    //SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, new Locale("es", "MX"));
    //SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, new Locale("es", "MX"));

    try {
        parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
        outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.e("formattedDateFromString", "Exception in formateDateFromstring(): " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return outputDate;

}
```

Answer (score 9):

## SimpleDateFormat

I use SimpleDateFormat **without custom pattern** to get actual date and time from the system in **the device's preselected** format:

```
public static String getFormattedDate() {
    //SimpleDateFormat called without pattern
    return new SimpleDateFormat().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

**returns**:

- 13.01.15 11:45
- 1/13/15 10:45 AM
- ...

Answer (score 8):

This code work for me!

```
Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence s = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss",d.getTime());
    Toast.makeText(this,s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 8):

Date format class work with cheat code to make date. Like

1. M -> 7, MM -> 07, MMM -> Jul , MMMM -> July
2. EEE -> Tue , EEEE -> Tuesday
3. z -> EST , zzz -> EST , zzzz -> Eastern Standard Time

You can check more cheats [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2016/08/date-formate.html).

Answer (score 7):

Use build in Time class!

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(0, 0, 17, 4, 5, 1999);
Log.i("DateTime", time.format("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"));
```

Comment: This is the optimal solution because it uses the lightweight Time object from the Android Framework: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

Comment: This is **not** the optimal solution: it doesn't respect the date format from the user's locale.

Answer (score 7):

Shortest way:

```
// 2019-03-29 16:11
String.format("%1$tY-%<tm-%<td %<tR", Calendar.getInstance())
```

`%tR` is short for `%tH:%tM`, `<` means to reuse last parameter(`1$`).

It is equivalent to `String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM", Calendar.getInstance())`

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: This is the shortest approach for sure, although it didn't work for me on Kotlin without removing the dollar symbol:


`String.format("%1tY-%<tm-%<td %<tR", Calendar.getInstance())`

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are generally correct. I should like to contribute the modern answer. The classes `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` used in most of the other answers, are long outdated and have caused trouble for many programmers over many years. Today we have so much better in `java.time`, AKA JSR-310, the modern Java date & time API. Can you use this on Android yet? Most certainly! The modern classes have been backported to Android in the ThreeTenABP project. See [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) for all the details.

This snippet should get you started:

```
    int year = 2017, month = 9, day = 28, hour = 22, minute = 45;
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
```

When I set my computer’s preferred language to US English or UK English, this prints:

```
Sep 28, 2017 10:45:00 PM
```

When instead I set it to Danish, I get:

```
28-09-2017 22:45:00
```

So it does follow the configuration. I am unsure exactly to what detail it follows your device’s date and time settings, though, and this may vary from phone to phone.

Answer (score 4):

This code would return the current date and time:

```
public String getCurrDate()
{
    String dt;
    Date cal = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    dt = cal.toLocaleString();
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: toLocaleString() is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

I use it like this:

```
public class DateUtils {
    static DateUtils instance;
    private final DateFormat dateFormat;
    private final DateFormat timeFormat;

    private DateUtils() {
        dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(MainApplication.context);
        timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(MainApplication.context);
    }

    public static DateUtils getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DateUtils();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized static String formatDateTime(long timestamp) {
        long milliseconds = timestamp * 1000;
        Date dateTime = new Date(milliseconds);
        String date = getInstance().dateFormat.format(dateTime);
        String time = getInstance().timeFormat.format(dateTime);
        return date + " " + time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Locale

To get date or time in locale format from milliseconds I used this:

### Date and time

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
dateFormat.format(date);
```

### Date

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
dateFormat.format(date);
```

### Time

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
dateFormat.format(date);
```

You can use other date style and time style. More info about styles [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
event.putExtra("startTime", "10/05/2012");
```

And when you are accessing passed variables:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(bundle.getString("startTime"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid j.u.Date

The Java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat in Java (and Android) are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. They are so bad that Sun/Oracle gave up on them, supplanting them with the new java.time package in Java 8 (not in Android as of 2014). The new [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) was inspired by the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

## Joda-Time

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) does work in Android.

Search StackOverflow for "Joda" to find many examples and much discussion.

A tidbit of source code using Joda-Time 2.4.

Standard format.

```
String output = DateTime.now().toString(); 
// Current date-time in user's default time zone with a String representation formatted to the ISO 8601 standard.
```

Localized format.

```
String output = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).print( DateTime.now() ); 
// Full (long) format localized for this user's language and culture.
```

Answer (score 1):

Back to 2016, When I want to customize the format (not according to the device configuration, as you ask...) I usually use the string resource file:

in strings.xml:

```
<string name="myDateFormat"><xliff:g id="myDateFormat">%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY</xliff:g></string>
```

In Activity:

```
Log.d(TAG, "my custom date format: "+getString(R.string.myDateFormat, new Date()));
```

This is also useful with the release of the new [Date Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

So I can have something like this in layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_release_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="@{@string/myDateFormat(vm.releaseDate)}"
    tools:text="0000"
    />
```

And in java class:

```
    MovieDetailViewModel vm = new MovieDetailViewModel();
    vm.setReleaseDate(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

The android Time class provides 3 formatting methods http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

This is how I did it:

```
/**
* This method will format the data from the android Time class (eg. myTime.setToNow())   into the format
* Date: dd.mm.yy Time: hh.mm.ss
*/
private String formatTime(String time)
{
    String fullTime= "";
    String[] sa = new String[2];

    if(time.length()>1)
    {
        Time t = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        t.parse(time);
        // or t.setToNow();
        String formattedTime = t.format("%d.%m.%Y %H.%M.%S");
        int x = 0;

        for(String s : formattedTime.split("\\s",2))
        {   
            System.out.println("Value = " + s);
            sa[x] = s;
            x++;
        }
        fullTime = "Date: " + sa[0] + " Time: " + sa[1];
    }
    else{
        fullTime = "No time data";
    }
    return fullTime;
}
```

I hope thats helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but it may help to someone

```
DateFormat.format(format, timeInMillis);
```

here `format` is what format you need

ex: "HH:mm" returns 15:30