# Display date AND time in user locale

Tags: android, datetime, formatting

I know I can use `android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat()` to format my dates, and `android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat` to format my times, but how do I format a datetime? Similar to the `getDateTimeInstance` method from `java.text.DateFormat`.

I'm currently just concatenating the result of both the `getDateFormat` and `getTimeFormat`'s formatters, but I don't know which way around the user prefers to have their dates and times shown.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do you need the String representation only? If yes, please have a look at
[`DateUtils.formatDateTime(Context context, long millis, int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateTime%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20int%29):

```
public static String formatDateTime (Context context, long millis, int flags)
```

in: [android.text.format.DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

Comment: This doesn't display the seconds.

Answer (score 11):

To extend the answer, here's a functional example

```
DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, epochTimeInMs, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE);
```

This would print `Apr 8` for a US Locale, or `8 de abr` for a Spanish Locale

You can see the full list of valid flags at [DateUtils documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateRange%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.Formatter,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)