# DateTime formatting in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime-format

I have a date/time that I get from a sqlite database and want to show in my Android app. I want it in the format :

9 November, 12:12. How do I do this? Is it best to format it before or after I enter it into the database?

Comment: Your question is how to format or when is it best to format the date?

Comment: Two questions in one. The first one is more urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android).

In your database, I would suggest you keep timestamps in there rather than the formatted strings. That way your program would still work if you decide to change the format later.

Comment: Thanks, found a nice link on one of the pages discussed in that link. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html