# Android Time Class format time

Tags: java, android, time, format

How do I format time using Android's Time Class.
I want to display time in this format "hh:mm AM/PM" . I have tried using the Time.format function but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Thanks

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android) is helpful.

Comment: [Do not use the Time class](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76439). It's going to be removed in the future and has many issues with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try this..

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
Date dt = new Date();
String strValue = timeFormat.format(dt);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question... he stated "the Android's Time Class" and your solution uses Java Date!

Comment: I think the OP didn't really know what he wanted.

Answer (score 7):

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(0, 0, 17, 4, 5, 1999);
Log.i("Time", time.format("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"));
```

Comment: [Do not use the Time class](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76439). It's going to be removed in the future and has many issues with it.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
String strTime = time.format("%I:%M %p");
```

Your answer can be derived from, but not limited to this link, a C++ reference about "ctime":
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/
I found this link to be very helpful deciphering the string formats used in my own work.

The [Android.Text.Format.Time.Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#format%28java.lang.String%29)  docs assumes you know something:
Where or how to read "man" page for strftime, which if you weren't familiar using Linux (or a Mac at the terminal) might require some creative web searching or know what "*See man strftime for what means what.*" referred to. Informal as it is in official documentation, it does build off and reference what has already has come before and is left as an exercise for the developer.

Comment: [Do not use the Time class](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76439). It's going to be removed in the future and has many issues with it.