# how to format a date?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

Hello I have been trying to format this date but it keeps giving me in unparsable date error?  I am trying to get a time stamp like 2011-06-24T19:55:37Z  to be June 24, 2011. here is the code I am using.  Also on a side note is contraction (like the 1st, 2nd, 3rd) possible?

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM d, yyyy", Locale.US);
 Date dt = sdf.parse("2011-03-01T17:55:15Z");
 time.setText("Time: " + dt.toString());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android

Comment: Not necessarily relevant. The issue in this question is parsing a given date, not formatting the current date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the format provided to SimpleDateFormat's constructor doesn't match the format of your date.

The string `MM d, yyyy` tells SimpleDateFormat how to interpret `2011-03-01T17:55:15Z`.

Building a format string is described in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I am still having some trouble. I need the date to look like June 24, 2011 from the timestamp 2011-06-24T19:55:37Z . Obviously I should strip off all the things I do not need.  But does the foramtter work if the format is some thing like MM d, yyyy   but the timestamp has the year first or do I need to switch everything around?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from another question within stackoverflow

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime()); 
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext()); 
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date)); 


DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS -05:00");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("2011-06-24T19:55:37Z");
```

Make sure the SimpleDateFormat matches your string

Comment: Works for the current time and date, but what about parsing a date as in the OP's question?

Comment: agreed with David.  But thank you for giving an example code.