# Get preferred date format string of Android system

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to get the format string used by the system when formatting a date using

```
DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(Context context).format(Date date)
```

Comment: Pls choose the other answer as the accepted one. The current one is a hack (as noted also by the person who answered).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a method to detect this format string. ( work for my case).

```
public static String getDateFormat(Context context){
        // 25/12/2013
        Calendar testDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        testDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        testDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
        testDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);

        Format format = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
        String testDateFormat = format.format(testDate.getTime());
        String[] parts = testDateFormat.split("/");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : parts){
            if(s.equals("25")){
                sb.append("dd/");
            }
            if(s.equals("12")){
                sb.append("MM/");
            }
            if(s.equals("2013")){
                sb.append("yyyy/");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
    }
```

**EDIT** Please check the Mark Melling's answer below **https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982842/945808** to have better solution. Mine was just a hack long time ago.

Comment: This will only work with Locales that split the date with `/` what is `.` or `-` is used for that locale

Comment: @draksia Then pls check the later answer from Mark Melling http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982842/945808

Comment: Yeah saw that I really need it for specific locales, I made some progress today hopefully it works

Comment: Great, I hope the author of this question could change the accepted answer to  Mark Melling's answer. My answer was just a hack at that time.

Comment: @VladMatvienko it is! as I said in the edit, pls check the answer from mark melling below

Answer (score 76):

To get the date format pattern you can do:

```
Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toLocalizedPattern();
```

Comment: Worked for me too, but is it possible to get the date and time format from it?

Comment: Getting the time instance as well. How can we ignore that?

currently: May 18, 2020 12:00:00
need: May 18, 2020

Answer (score 5):

There is a static method in the API that you can call like this:

```
Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
```

There is more discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android).

Comment: That dateFormat object has a private field called pattern which is exactly what I am looking for. But it is private and has no getter to get it. How can I get it without reflection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
private static DateFormat mDateFormat;
private static DateFormat mTimeFormat;

mDateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(this);
mTimeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this);

public static String getSystemDateFormat() {
    return ((SimpleDateFormat) mDateFormat).toPattern();
}

public static String getSystemTimeFormat() {
    return ((SimpleDateFormat) mTimeFormat).toPattern();
}

public static String getSystemDateTimeFormat() {
    return getSystemDateFormat() + " " + getSystemTimeFormat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

based on an answer above:

```
String pattern = Settings.System.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
                String format;
                if (pattern.indexOf("d")<pattern.indexOf("M"))
                    format = "d/M";
                else
                    format = "M/d";
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
```

and then use the SimpleDateFormat to format your Date objects. It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleDateFormat

I use SimpleDateFormat **without custom pattern** to get actual date and time in **preferred** format from system:

```
public static String getFormattedDate() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(); //called without pattern
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}
```

**returns**:

- 13.01.15 11:45
- 1/13/15 10:45 AM
- ...

Comment: This is not working on my devices even if I change the time format on the settings...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) documentation:

> To format a date for the current Locale, use one of the static factory
>   methods:

```
myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate);
```

And to format it for a *different* locale:

```
myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRANCE).format(myDate);
```

Comment: Seems to be that my question has been misunderstood. What I need is to get the current date format string which is used by the system when DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(Context context).format(Date date) is called.

I dont need the formatted date string. What I need is the format string itself. Like "mm/dd/yyyy" or whichever the system uses according to the locale set on the device.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible in Android. The method getDateInstance() is undefined for the type DateFormat.

Comment: Causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar

Comment: Does any one know how to get the actual pattern like yyyy-MM-dd?

Answer (score 0):

```
String shortDateFormat  = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
```

Comment: My system is set to return dd/MM/yyyy and this gives me dd-MM-YYYY - so not the correct seperators. The answer above by Mark Melling however does return the correct system pattern.

Comment: got it from docs: [android dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#DATE_FORMAT).
Anyway answer above by Mark Melling - better solution.