# convert date to format of the locale format type in android with xamarin with visual studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How to get current format of the locale so that i can Format datetime with the format i get.

Means if i got the format then i can format that.

DateTime.Now.ToString(format);

This i am doing in visual studio with xamarin for creating Android application from C#.net.

Please help me for getting me the format.

Thanks & Regards
Parvez

Answer (score 0):

You can use the culture info as formatter.

```
    var d = DateTime.Now;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        d.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        d.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));
```

Comment: this doesn't work. i need the format as soon as user change the format to MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy.
i will use that format then
fromDate.ToString(format);

Comment: i did try this also
Java.Text.DateFormat df = Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.GetDateFormat(this.appContext);
var str = df.Format(new Java.Util.Date());

which give me the same format which i change but this takes Java.Util.Date() as paramter.


<br/>
I need to put 
var str = df.Format(DBfromDate);

@MilenPavlov

Comment: thnaks for your answer but i am done with the issue by below code

Java.Text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.GetDateFormat(CurrentContext);

DateFormatPattern = ((Java.Text.SimpleDateFormat)dateFormat).ToPattern(); 

from @MarkMelling post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235934/get-preferred-date-format-string-of-android-system

Answer (score 0):

try building the date format that you require, example below:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
string newdateformat = string.Format("{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:0000}", now.Month, now.Day, now.Year);
```

Comment: thnaks for your answer but i am done with the issue by below code

Java.Text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.GetDateFormat(CurrentContext);

DateFormatPattern = ((Java.Text.SimpleDateFormat)dateFormat).ToPattern(); 

from @MarkMelling post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235934/get-preferred-date-format-string-of-android-system

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to format a `DateTime` to a string representation depending on the settings of the device (the locale).
You can do it like so:

```
var javaDate = new Date(YourDateTime.ToUnixTime()*1000);
var dt = DateFormat.DateTimeInstance;
SomeTextView.Text = string.Format("DateTime is: {0}", dt.Format(javaDate));
```

Notice that I used an extension method `ToUnixTime()` which converts `DateTime` to an Epoch time (also known as unix time) representation. You can find it easily even here on Stackoverflow.

(you can use DateFormat.DateInstance if you don't want the time part of the string)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thnaks for your answer but i am done with the issue by below code

Java.Text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.GetDateFormat(CurrentContext);

DateFormatPattern = ((Java.Text.SimpleDateFormat)dateFormat).ToPattern(); 

from @MarkMelling post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235934/get-preferred-date-format-string-of-android-system