# Convert a String to each device Date Format

Tags: android

I have a string like this "2018-08-30 03:45:39". Now I want to show it on view depend on each devide's datetime formats. Ex: My phone's datetime format is dd/mm/yyyy, my friend's phone is mm/dd/yyy. Can someone help me?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982842/3921977

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [toLocalizedPattern()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern()) method

Try the following code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    String dateLocalizedFormatPattern = simpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
    Log.d("DatePattern",dateLocalizedFormatPattern )
```