# Getting different DateFormat result on emulator and on phone-Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, date-format, datetime-format

I wanted to display date and time at a particular instance in my android app.I used the following piece of code to achieve it.

```
Date now = new Date();
final String time = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,DateFormat.SHORT).format(now);
```

Now the problem is that on emulator it shows dates and time in a perfect format just the way i wanted

```
Sep 1,2012 10:30pm
```

But when i run my app on phone it displays date and time on the following format:

```
2012 9 1 10:30
```

Can anyone please tell me why im getting different behavior on emulator and on phone? and what should i do in order to achieve the same result on phone as im getting on emulator?

Thank You!!

Comment: check this link once   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android

Comment: @shassss thank you for your response.I did checked that link.But i didn't get that how can i get the result like "Sep 1, 2012 10:30pm" from those examples posted on that question?

Comment: Have you looked at all at the locale settings you've got on the emulator vs the real device?

Comment: @brianestet thank you for your response.yes its different but i'm trying to get same date everywhere regardless of device,OS,settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date formats may change phone to phone, pc to phone or so. 
But you may use a date formatter so that you can achive uniformity.

[Documentation - SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[Example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-get-current-date-and-time-in-different-format/)

Comment: thank you for your response.i almost got the result.I changed my format in this line > SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"); to SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a");
this is giving me date and time in format 9 03,2012 2:05 AM.Can you please tell me how can i make month "9" to display as "Sep"?

Comment: it should be 
"yyyy-MMMM-dd" ex output: 1970-January-01 ---AND---
"yyyy-MMM-dd" ex output: 1970-Jan-01

Comment: thank for your response.i tried that but it didn't work.It works after adding Locale.

Answer (score 2):

Sukitha your hint works. I guess Viking missed it.

Anyways, here it goes.(Tested in Motorola DROID)

```
String format = "MMM d,yyyy H:m a";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println("Time : "+sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Time : "+sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())), 1000).show();
```

Output: **Time : Jan 4,1970 6:52 AM**

Comment: thanks for your response.This code gave me an output 9 2,2012 2:0 AM thus its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Use the following code then you will get it same on both emulator and device.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a");
String formattedDate1 = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: thank you for your response.im running android 2.2 on both is that what you meant by setting up api?? Also i want to achieve same result regardless of api is that possible?