# Automatic Date and Time in EditText - Android

Tags: java, android, date, time

How do I get an edittext field to display the date and another to display the time automatically on open?

I have the edittexts coded as follows:

XML Code:

```
<!-- Creating autocomplete text field for date -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/autoD8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/autoTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoTime"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

    <!-- Creating autocomplete text field for time -->
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/autoTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputPlace"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />
```

All I have in my java code section at the moment is as follows:

```
EditText autoD8, autoTime;
```

Comment: I suggest going through the Android tutorial. Maybe I don't understand the question properly, but it seems like you'd be able to do this just by getting the date/time in your Activity's onCreate and formatting it. You can find how to format the date here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android

Comment: Please, show as the code of your Activity. What you are asking is hard (if not impossible) to do in XML.

Comment: If I changed it to a textview would it be much easier?

Answer (score 2):

That should be something like that in your `onCreate()` :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    EditText autoD8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.autoD8);
    EditText autoTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.autoTime);

    SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat timeF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    String date = dateF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String time = timeF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    autoD8.setText(time);
    autoTime.setText(time);
}
```

More formats [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: It's saying it cannot convert from SimpleDateFormat to DateFormat

Comment: It's also saying method format is not applicable in type DateFormat for the arguments (date)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html
Just get the date and time and set values in EditTexts

Answer (score 0):

One way is override your Activity/Fragment's onStart()/onCreate() and set time yourself. I didn't see any attribute which can auto fill date/time in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#EditText