# Convert date to friendly format using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, time, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a date such as `Mon Jul 28 00:00:00 CDT 2014` to something a bit more user friendly, such as `Mon 6/28`.  What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
        String date_string = "Mon Jul 28 00:00:00 CDT 2014";

        SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ccc LLL F HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"); //please notice the    capital M
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ccc LLL/yyyy");

        try {
            Date date = inputFormatter.parse(date_string);
            String text = outputFormatter.format(date);
            System.out.println(text);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I use System.out.println to see what outputFormatter is set to, the result is: `Sun Jan/2015`

Comment: Can you see the connection between `ccc LLL/yyyy` & `Sun Jan/2015`? Check out [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: check this so you can see the actual pattern letters http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I'm sorry, is this a stupid question?  Not sure why I got downvoted... I'll look at the docs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you format date and time in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ccc LLL/yyyy");
```

to

```
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M/dd");
```

`EEE`  --> **Mon**

`EEEE`  --> **Monday**

`MM`  --> **06**

`M`  --> **6**

`dd`  --> **28**

**EDIT**

```
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/c5rVT5

Comment: Thank you, that did change the format of the output to what I want, however, it is still displaying incorrect information.  The output is Sun 1/11.

Comment: It should be Mon 6/28.

Comment: Thank you!!  It works perfectly :D  Wish I wouldn't have gotten downvoted, but otherwise, I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

"Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number."

If you want the number version, use the shorter format in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M/dd");
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details.

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM/yyyy");
```

This will print : Mon Jul/2014

If you use :

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE L/d");
```

This will print : Mon 7/28