# Android - change Date format to - dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm

Tags: android, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I have a Date object like this:

```
Fri Jan 29 13:22:57 GMT+01:00 2016
```

And I need it to look like this:

***29.01.2016 13:22***

How can I do that ?

Comment: What did you try so far? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At First Post Your Code .

Please follow **[How do you format date and time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)**

Code for **SimpleDateFormat** . Just check the **logic** .

```
SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-yyyy-MM HHmm");
Date GetDate = new Date();
String DateStr = timeStampFormat.format(GetDate);
```

Now replace `-` as `.`

**`DateStr = DateStr.replace("-", ".");`**