# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference in Android

Tags: android, datetime-format

I want to convert **strSqliteDate﹕ = 2016-01-14 05:34:50 PM**  into **2016-01-14** .After converting all dates my application was crash and getting error of

```
02-01 12:03:15.204    7619-7619/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
02-01 12:03:15.204    7619-7619/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1035)
02-01 12:03:15.204    7619-7619/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:577)
```

At this line   `date = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);`

and second getting error at this `line = calendar.setTime(date);`

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
>               at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1195)

Here is date conversion code in DBhelper class

```
String strSqliteDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActionDate"));
                Log.e(" strSqliteDate "," = " + strSqliteDate);

                String result = "";
                Date date = null;
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                try
                {
                     date = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                result = printFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                Log.e("result = ","==========>"+result);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3930115/5456493

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before Use variable strSqliteDate  check whether it is null or not?

```
String strSqliteDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActionDate"));
if(strSqliteDate != null && !strSqliteDate .isEmpty())
{

  Log.e(" strSqliteDate "," = " + strSqliteDate);

            String result = "";
            Date date = null;
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try
            {
                 date = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            result = printFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            Log.e("result = ","==========>"+result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference at
>   java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1195)

According to your Question ,You should use `substring()` & Do check your **database** is `null` or not .

> This method has two variants and returns a new string that is a
>   substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at
>   the specified index and extends to the end of this string or up to
>   endIndex - 1 if second argument is given.

```
.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

> strSqliteDate = 2016-01-14 05:34:50 PM
>
> System.out.println(strSqliteDate.substring(0, 11) );

Answer (score 0):

Use the **subString** method refers [Refers link](http://www.javatpoint.com/substring)

```
strSqliteDate.subString(0,10)

Output will be==>> 2016-01-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `date = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);`
`strSqliteDate` is **null** that is why u are getting NPE

Answer (score 0):

At line

```
result = printFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

pass the reference of **Date** class in the argument of `formate()`..