# How to reset time to 00:00:00 and change to timeMilis?

Tags: android, date, time, calendar, datetimepicker

I had question: 
long `timeInMillis = 1488943098615;`
//-> Wed Mar 08 2017 10:18:18

How to switch from `1488943098615` (wed mar 08 2017 10:18:18) -> **?** (timeInMillis) (wed mar 08 2017 **00:00:00**). That means taking all the time of the day. Eliminating hours and minutes.

Comment: oh No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android  return the date i want to gettimeInMillis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // defaults to currentTimeInMs
//cal.setTimeInMillis(myCurrentTime); //if you have a timestamp already
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //reset just the hour and minute parts
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);      //leaving the same date
long msAtMidnight = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Thanks you! I need this

Answer (score 0):

You get current date then you sub () current date with hours = 0, minutes = 0, second = 0

> Vitual code

```
Date currentDate = miliSecond (yyyyMMddHHmmss)
Date currentStartDate = miliSecond(yyyyMMdd000000)
miliSecondSub = currentDate - currentStartDate;
Date now = Date(miliSecondSub)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have already done it