# How do you get create a date and get only the month?

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-date

What is the proper way to make a date in android? "Date date = new Date, date = 1995/06/10"?

Also, how do i get a only the month of the date? most of the tutorials around have a simpledateformat with the "YYYY-MMD-dd HH mm ss", but how do i grab only the "MMM"?

Comment: Use [Calender](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android

Comment: could you give an example please, i learn better that way

Comment: A lots of examples available in link above . And if you just try to search the same title you will get more posts like this. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format date and time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Comment: Don’t use the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Rather consider adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Many programming languages are used for programming for Android. Since you mentioned the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class, I am assuming that you are using Java, if not the language then at least the Java platform/runtime. Then I warmly recommend `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. For example, using Java:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila"));
    LocalDate backThen = LocalDate.of(1995, Month.JUNE, 10);
```

Since it is never the same date everywhere on the planet, make sure you specify your desired time zone for getting today’s date. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day.

To get only the month for use in your program:

```
    Month m = today.getMonth();
```

Running my code just now this returned `Month.APRIL`. `Month` is an enum with the 12 months of the Gregorian calendar.

If you wanted to print just the month to the user, your format pattern string should just contain only `MMM` (or `MMMM` for full month name):

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", Locale.forLanguageTag("fil-PH"));
    System.out.println(backThen.format(monthFormatter));
```

This printed:

> Hun

I didn’t know June was Hunyo in Philippinese. I know now. Supply a different locale to get the month name in a different language.

And yes, very many tutorials and other pages still float around from when we used `SimpleDateFormat` and its now long outdated friends. Your best bet is to ignore them.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [I want to develop Android Apps — What languages should I learn?](https://www.androidauthority.com/develop-android-apps-languages-learn-391008/)