# Turning timeInMills to a 24hour/Date

Tags: java, android, epoch, milliseconds, time-format

Is there any source code for turning the timeInMills to a 24hour/Date like from the messenger app. When the timeInMills is below 24 hour it will return like this `16:15` but when it is over 24hour it will return like this `THU at 16:15`. I am currently creating a chat app and I want to add this to my app.

Comment: This is from a difference in the current time and the particular posting? I am not aware of a specific library call, but in general set the particular format for a date (e.g., "HH:mm", or "ddd HH:mm") based upon the time difference. You may want to include months or years if the time gap is sufficient (kind of how the Linux `ls` provides information). See [How do you format date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Comment: Do you mean if it’s over 24 hours *ago*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Beware this line: `long last24hTimestamp = current - MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;`

I'm calculating on behalf of UTC time.

To get the local time, you should take into account the timezone.

---

So basically you have to calculate if the timestamp `timeInMillis` is within the last 24h then use one format otherwise use another format.

This will help you:

```
public static final long MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;// In real app you should pre-calculate this value
public static final String RECENT_DATE_FORMAT = "HH:mm";
public static final String OLD_DATE_FORMAT = "E' at 'HH:mm";

public static String displayTime(long timestamp) {
  long current = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
  long last24hTimestamp = current - MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;

  if (timestamp > last24hTimestamp) {

   // Received message within a day, use first format
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(RECENT_DATE_FORMAT);
   return sdf.format(new Date(timestamp));
  } else {
    // Message is older than 1 day. Use second format

  }

}
```

Something you should take care of:

1. Consider parsing with timezone/localization if your app run in multiple places
2. If you're using java 8, try to use `DateTimeFormatter`. It's threadsafe and you can use a static instance per date format, no need to initialize `SimpleDateFormat` everytime you want to format a date

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

For work with dates or times in Java I recommend `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

```
static DateTimeFormatter lessThan24HoursAgoFormatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
static DateTimeFormatter moreThan24HoursAgoFormatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE 'at' HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
static ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Yakutat");

public static String getDisplayString(long timeInMills) {
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMills)
            .atZone(zone)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    ZonedDateTime currentTimeYesterday = ZonedDateTime.now(zone).minusDays(1);
    if (dateTime.isAfter(currentTimeYesterday)) {
        return dateTime.format(lessThan24HoursAgoFormatter);
    } else {
        return dateTime.format(moreThan24HoursAgoFormatter);
    }
}
```

Running just now

- `getDisplayString(1_525_402_083_258L)` returned `Thu at 18:48`.
- `getDisplayString(1_525_490_972_172L)` returned just `19:29`.

Please put your desired time zone where I put America/Yakutat. I recommend you insert checks that the millis denote a time that is not more than a week ago and not in the future, since the returned string would be confusing in these cases.

It’s also a possibility that a library exists out there that will format a string akin to what you desire. Use your search engine.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).