# Convert Cloud Firestore Timestamp to readable date

Tags: java, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

How to convert timestamped retrieved from firebase firestore database and compare it with the current date and time.

```
 db.collection("users").document(user.getuid).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        String date = documentSnapshot.getData().get("last_login_date").toString();
                       
                    }
                });
```

Conver the date to readable and deduct it from the current time to show the difference in days, hours and minutes

The output of date variable is in below format

```
Timestamp(seconds=1558532829, nanoseconds=284000000)
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your document.

Comment: @AlexMamo checkout the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FDJ9noHt11EZrMTsq0sCTXjIn5607vn1?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5):

When you read a timestamp type field out of a document in Cloud Firestore, it will arrive as a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) type object in Java.  Be sure to read the linked Javadoc to find out more about it.

```
Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) documentSnapshot.getData().get("last_login_date");
```

The Timestamp has two components, seconds and nanoseconds.  If those values are not useful to you, you can convert the Timestamp to a Java Date object using its [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#public-methods_1) method, but you might lose some of the timestamp's nanosecond precision, since Date objects only use microsecond precision.

```
Date date = timestamp.toDate();
```

With a Date object, you should be able to easily use other date formatting tools, such as [Android's own date formatting options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android).  You can also use the Date's `toMillis()` method to compare it with the current time from `System.currentTimeMillis()`;

See:

- [How do you format date and time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)
- [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use this.**

```
    String date= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(timestamp.getTime());
```

it mostly use in RecyclerView's Adapter class.