# How can I implement Firestore timestamp in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a Spring Boot application and I have a timestamp variable in Firestore DB I want to send date in that field. How can I do that?

[image: This is from my Firebase DB I am using dob as time stamp]

[image: This is my data type am using to call that timestamp from DB but that is wrong I am not able to send the correct date]

This is my service I am sending data to Firebase

```
    public Patient addPatient(Patient patients) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException  {
    
    Firestore dbFirestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
    ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiResult = dbFirestore.collection(this.fireStoreCollection).document(patients.getUserId()).set(patients);
    return patients;
}
```

[image: my Firestore DB screenshot I want to send dob in this]

Comment: Hi, Can you be more clear with your question? Do you want to retrieve Firestore's timestamp data in readable form or do you wanna add the timestamp data into Firestore?

Comment: Hi,   Both i want to do i want to retrieve as well as want to send. above screenshot i have added that data into databse manually . I want to do that same with my api . i have written get API Also i want that all in readable form as well as to send in json to the db.

Comment: Hi, can you check if [adding server timestamp field to the Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355540/adding-server-timestamp-field-to-the-object-which-being-added) and [Convert Cloud Firestore timestamp to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259128/convert-cloud-firestore-timestamp-to-readable-date)  helps you?

Comment: HI, not exactly getting the desired output  in comment i am not able to share images or code ..  Please if possible you can share me your contact email . so you can help me in better way .      Thanks .

Comment: i am sharing a document in which i have added some screen shot with which you can check once.. --------------- 
 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aZs3YIiTyGhJgMy7tsZgkE9fD4eNDkqgg7KZWZ6YHKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: after using Map i was able to add the data but that was not as the desired output i have shared screenshot in doc.

Comment: Hey, so I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704887/15774177) on stackoverflow, can you take a look at it and see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Zeenath S N above, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62704816/16313960) has your answer.

You can use **ServerTimestamp** annotation. Try changing

```
private Timestamp dob;
```

to

```
private Date dob;
```

in your code.

Alternatively, as below:

> If you want to write a timestamp field, and you can't use a server timestamp, you will need to either provide a regular Java Date object, or a Firebase Timestamp object. Either of these types of values will convert to a timestamp field in the document.
>
> When you query for the document, the field will always show up in the document snapshot as a Timestamp type object.