# How to Format Date in android from String

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, localdate

Log print
`dateStr` -> `2019-07-05 12:05:36`
`currentDate` -> `Fri Jul 05 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2019`

I need -> `Fri 05 Jul 2019` and also translated to Macedonian locale

```
String dateStr = obj.getString("sent_date");
            Log.d("date", dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            Date currentDate = null;
            try {
                currentDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
                Log.d("date", currentDate.toString());
```

Comment: avoid from using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format date and time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SimpleDateFormat with Macedonian local you can do like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("mk", "MK"));
```

or you can use DateFormat instead in this way:

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRANCE);
myDate = df.parse(dateStr);
```

for more formatting options you can look at [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the date format string,

```
SimpleDateFormat resultFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd MMM yyyy", new Locale("mk", "MK"));
resultFormat.format(currentDate)
```

Should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
  @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static String formatTime(String dateFormat) {
        String inputTimePattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy";
        String outputTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputTimePattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputTimePattern, new Locale("mk" ,""));
        Date date;
        try {
            date = inputFormat.parse(dateFormat);
            return outputFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateFormat;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, formatTime("Fri Jul 05 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2019"));

    Output -> 2019-07-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function just put your desire date format

```
private String returnData(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    localDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    try {
        localDateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String finalDate = localDateFormat.format(new Date());
    return finalDate;
 }
```